# Facebook page name not available

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm trying to register a Facebook page, I'd like the name to be like www.facebook.com/xxx

So when I type on browser www.facebook.com/xxx it tells me the page I'm looking for doesn't exist.

But when I try to create the page I got: name already taken...any idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s not aboug programming but page support

Comment: Not sure if you _literally_ mean `xxx` as page name … but if you do, that one might be blocked (for obvious reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is very "rushy" network. Which means it will take a while (couple of minutes or a hour) to fully create your page including this www.facebook.com/xxx you want. My advice is to wait some time then for sure you'll have it!

Comment: I already created the page skipping the choice of the name. So now I wait some hors then go to settings -> about -> and choice my name?

Comment: If you haven't chose your name yet , yes!